# Сломался сайт на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Перестал работать сайт на фреймворке Laravel 5.6, не работают команды php artisan, composer. Выдается во всех случаях ошибка:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: factory in
>   /project/config/database/factories/UserFactory.php on line 16
>
> In UserFactory.php line 16:
>
> Call to a member function define() on null

Пробовал обновить composer (composer update, composer self-update), переустановить фреймворк (composer install), запустить/остановить приложение php artisan up/down. В консоли все та же ошибка.
В браузере при открытии сайта она же:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Call to a member function define() on null
>   /project/config/database/factories/UserFactory.php

Буду очень признателен за содержательный ответ!

Comment: просто так сломался чтоли? может вы что-то делали... откатиться не пробовали?

Comment: Представьте себе просто так...после команды php artisan down в активный режим больше не возвращается. Что значит откатить? Как это делается? Я уже пробовал laravel cache:clear, composer cache:clear - все та же ошибка. Там что-то с переменной $faker. Она почему-то null, судя по ошибке.

Comment: Я полагаю, что нарушились связи во фреймворке. Как исправить?

Comment: А покажите нам эту самую 16-ю строку! Я думаю, что там зря $ стоит перед factory(), но хочу убедиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, нашел проблему. Случайно каким-то образом через ftp перенес папку database в папку config. Она там не должна быть: /project/config/database/factories. Вернул ее обратно в корень приложения и все заработало!

Comment: Мы всегда рады вам помочь!